# Why can't i see snapshots on reusing a VM harddisk on a new/different machine?

Tags: vmware-workstation

I am using VMware Workstation 9.0.

I saved a complete VM which had a lot of snapshots, now i am reusing the VMware harddisk on a different (new) machine, but on clicking the snapshots tab, i can't see any snapshot listed.

Where am i missing? Please help.

EDIT: Explicitly using a snapshot disk, browsing like SLES11000002.vmdk solves it, but why the snapshots aren't listed?

Comment: AFAIK you can' transfer them.  http://superuser.com/questions/587738/transfer-vm-with-snapshots-to-another-system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Snapshots are a property of the virtual machine, not the virtual hard drive. If all you're doing is using attaching the hard drive to a new virtual machine, then you're not going to see the machine snapshots. You have to copy/export the entire machine configuration, not just copy the hard drive.

Comment: Have you actually tried this?  I have never seen this successfully work.

Comment: Ah, workstation. You're right. I don't think there is a way to move snapshots between machines in workstation.